# lisp list with even position elements

Tags: lisp

I am trying to get a list from the list given as parameter that has only elements at even positions.

So if I have '(a b c d e f) I should get '(a c e).
I also want to do it iteratively with do.

```
(defun pozpar (lst)
  (do ((l lst (cdr l))
       (y 0 (+ y 1))
       (x '() (cond ((eql 0 (mod y 2))
                     (cons (car l) x)))))
      ((null l) x)))
POZPAR
> (pozpar '(a b c d e f))
NIL
```

I don't see what's wrong with the code and why the list has only nil.

Comment: This looks like Common Lisp, but I'm only guessing. Please tag a specific language, in addition to the [lisp] tag. The latter includes a broad family of languages including CLIsp, ELisp, Racket, and Clojure, and they end up being fairly different.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo : CLisp is not a language. Common Lisp is called Common Lisp and usually abbreviated as CL. CLISP is a specific implementation of Common Lisp, like SBCL and LispWorks are others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the "else" clause of `cond`.

Try this

```
* (defun pozpar(lst)
    (do ((l lst (cdr l))
         (y 0 (+ y 1))
         (x '() (cond ((eql 0 (mod y 2)) (cons (car l) x))
                      (t x))))
        ((null l) x)))

* (reverse (pozpar '(a b c d e f)))
(A C E)
```